# How to share the wireless network through terminal?

Tags: networking, playonlinux

In windows this command

`netsh wlan start hosted network ssid=username password=password`

used to work for sharing the wireless LAN or say used to work as the connectify-me.

So how can I use this facility in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iwconfig` - configure a wireless network interface

see `man iwconfig` for its usage.

Comment: You could always use code `` tags....